# After installing a dictionary deinstalling apps doesn‘t work

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore, software-update

I installed a dictionary under the newest ipados and since then I‘m not able to deinstall the app. I tried already using the deinstallation over the manager of the ipad-storage under the  general settings but there isn‘t even the button for deinstalling apps, even if I choose another app.
Do you have a hint except erasing the ipad and renewing the system?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  It's a little difficult understanding your question as it's currently written.  Are you trying to uninstall an app from your iPad?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to uninstall apps but since I installed that dictionary app, I have no possibility to do that. Have you got a hint?

Comment: You can uninstall the same it's always been.  Tap and hold the icon for several seconds.  You'll first see a menu list of items.  If 'delete' isn't in that list, keep holding the icon until it starts to wiggle.  From there you can tap the 'X' to delete the app.  Let me know if that worked or not.

Comment: That is the problem, after the apps start to wiggle the x does not appear. Even in the menu that appears before the apps wiggle there is no option to delete apps.

Comment: Some Apple apps can't be deleted.  Is this an Apple app or 3rd-party app?   Also, please add your iPad model number and OS version to your question.

Comment: It is an IPad of the 6.th generation with IPad Os 13.2.2. It's modelnumber is: MR7J2FD/A and A1893 is also displayed. I installed a third party app that is trustworthy but since then I'm not able to delete any app on the pad.

Comment: Go to `Settings -> Screen Time -> Content & Privacy Restrictions`.  Tell me if the 'Content & Privacy Restrictions' switch is turned on or off.

Comment: It is switched on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, I think this is related to Screen Time.

Assuming you're the owner and don't want Screen Time on or that it was turned on by mistake, simply go to `Settings -> Screen Time -> Content & Privacy`.

Tap on `iTunes & App Store Purchases`.  Make sure the setting for 'Deleting Apps' is 'Allow'.

From there you can back out and leave the rest of the settings as-is or turn off the restrictions.  To turn off restrictions, turn off the 'Content & Privacy Restrictions' switch.  You might be prompted for your password or PIN to do this.

The image below is from an iPhone but the flow and look are similar to the iPad.

[image]

Comment: You saved me. Thank you very much. It worked well.